# 7 wonders: copying science

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-cities, 7-wonders-leaders

I'm playing 7 Wonders with the Cities and Leaders expansions.

1. If your neighbours has less science buildings than you have mask, then I assume you cannot use them all. You can only copy the symbol of 1 building once?
2. If one of your neighbours has a leader which carries a symbol, can you copy this?7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rules state:

- At the end of the game, each mask allows the controlling player to copy the scientific symbol of a green card present in one of the two neighboring cities.
- If a player possesses multiple [mask] symbols, he or she can only copy a given card once, and must thus copy as many different cards as they have [mask] symbols.
- A player can copy two identical cards (if they have enough masks) if both neighboring cities have a copy (copy a Workshop card in the left city and a second Workshop card in the right city).

Example: At the end of the game, Alex has 2 cards with the [mask] symbol. The player to his left only has one green card, with the compass symbol. The player to his right has played no green cards. Alex’s first [mask] therefore counts as a [compass] symbol, but his second [mask] is useless as there are no other symbols to copy. If the player to the left of Alex had had 2 green cards with a [compass] symbol each, Alex’s 2 masks could’ve counted as [compass].

So the wording is pretty clear. For each mask symbol you control, you may copy the symbol of a single green card owned by either adjacent player. Hence,

1. You may not copy the same building, even if you have more masks than buildings.
2. You may not copy the symbol on a leader, since they are not a building / green card.